# jhipster formatting scss files with trailing commas during file writing phase

Tags: jhipster

My template (themes.scss.ejs) file has the following content (with formatting),

```
body.light,
body .light {
    $base-light-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
        color: ($palettes)
    ));
```

but the file that gets generated looks like the following,

```
body.light,
body .light {
    $base-light-theme: mat.define-light-theme(
        (
            color: (
                $palettes,
            ),
        )
    );
```

**see how the trailing commas are added. This is causing the build to fail with the following error,

```
./src/@fuse/styles/themes.scss.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[1].use[0]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[1].use[1]!./src/@fuse/styles/themes.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: $map: ((primary: (50: var(--fuse-primary-50), 100: var(--fuse-primary-100), 200: var(--fuse-primary-200), 300: var(--fuse-primary-300), 400: var(--fuse-primary-400), 500: var(--fuse-primary-500), 600: var(--fuse-primary-600), 700: var(--fuse-primary-700), 800: var(--fuse-primary-800), 900: var(--fuse-primary-900), contrast: (50: var(--fuse-on-primary-50), 100: var(--fuse-on-primary-100), 200: var(--fuse-on-primary-200), 300: var(--fuse-on-primary-300), 400: var(--fuse-on-primary-400), 500: var(--fuse-on-primary-500), 600: var(--fuse-on-primary-600), 700: var(--fuse-on-primary-700), 800: var(--fuse-on-primary-800), 900: var(--fuse-on-primary-900)), default: var(--fuse-primary), lighter: var(--fuse-primary-100), darker: var(--fuse-primary-700), text: var(--fuse-primary), default-contrast: var(--fuse-on-primary), lighter-contrast: var(--fuse-on-primary-100), darker-contrast: var(--fuse-on-primary-700)), accent: (50: var(--fuse-accent-50), 100: var(--fuse-accent-100), 200: var(--fuse-accent-200), 300: var(--fuse-accent-300), 400: var(--fuse-accent-400), 500: var(--fuse-accent-500), 600: var(--fuse-accent-600), 700: var(--fuse-accent-700), 800: var(--fuse-accent-800), 900: var(--fuse-accent-900), contrast: (50: var(--fuse-on-accent-50), 100: var(--fuse-on-accent-100), 200: var(--fuse-on-accent-200), 300: var(--fuse-on-accent-300), 400: var(--fuse-on-accent-400), 500: var(--fuse-on-accent-500), 600: var(--fuse-on-accent-600), 700: var(--fuse-on-accent-700), 800: var(--fuse-on-accent-800), 900: var(--fuse-on-accent-900)), default: var(--fuse-accent), lighter: var(--fuse-accent-100), darker: var(--fuse-accent-700), text: var(--fuse-accent), default-contrast: var(--fuse-on-accent), lighter-contrast: var(--fuse-on-accent-100), darker-contrast: var(--fuse-on-accent-700)), warn: (50: var(--fuse-warn-50), 100: var(--fuse-warn-100), 200: var(--fuse-warn-200), 300: var(--fuse-warn-300), 400: var(--fuse-warn-400), 500: var(--fuse-warn-500), 600: var(--fuse-warn-600), 700: var(--fuse-warn-700), 800: var(--fuse-warn-800), 900: var(--fuse-warn-900), contrast: (50: var(--fuse-on-warn-50), 100: var(--fuse-on-warn-100), 200: var(--fuse-on-warn-200), 300: var(--fuse-on-warn-300), 400: var(--fuse-on-warn-400), 500: var(--fuse-on-warn-500), 600: var(--fuse-on-warn-600), 700: var(--fuse-on-warn-700), 800: var(--fuse-on-warn-800), 900: var(--fuse-on-warn-900)), default: var(--fuse-warn), lighter: var(--fuse-warn-100), darker: var(--fuse-warn-700), text: var(--fuse-warn), default-contrast: var(--fuse-on-warn), lighter-contrast: var(--fuse-on-warn-100), darker-contrast: var(--fuse-on-warn-700))),) is not a map.
    ╷
181 │     $primary: map.get($color-settings, primary);
    │               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/_theming.scss 181:15  define-light-theme()
  src/@fuse/styles/themes.scss 73:22                                root stylesheet
```

I am using the
`writeFilesToDisk(files, generator = this, returnFiles = false, rootTemplatesPath)` method in the `generator-base.js` which then calls the `template(source, destination, generator, options = {}, context)` in `generator-base-private.js`.

I inspected the response (res) inside this method,

```
jhipsterUtils
      .renderContent(source, _this, _context, options)
      .then(res => {
           _this.fs.write(customDestination, res);
            return customDestination;
       })
```

and the raw content did not have any trailing commas. So, it looks like the _this.fs.write method is doing the formatting + adding the trailing commas.

Is there an option to not have the formatting done by the yomans fs module. I looked around in the code base and searched the yomans documentation but couldn't find any.

Any help is greatly appreciated...

***Note:*** I manually removed the extra commas from the generated code and everything worked fine.

**04/04/2022 Update:**
Wasn't sure if this formatting was done by ejs by default or one of the options provided by jhipster to it (tro yoman generator) is causing this. So created a pure yoman generator and this re-formatting doesn't occur there. So this proves that jhipster's options to yoman's fs/ejs is causing this formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out what was happening and I think I can answer my own question to help someone in the future...

adding a `--skip-prettier` to the command basically skipped the formatting part and was able to get the exact same formatting as the source *.ejs file without the influence of the prettier.

In `/generators/bootstrap/index.js` _commitSharedFs method builds the transformation object that has an array of different transformers and one of them is the prettier. Adding the above command basically skips the prettier transformer in the array,

```
const transformStreams = [
      // multi-step changes the file path, should be executed earlier in the pipeline
      new MultiStepTransform(),
      ...(skipYoResolve ? [] : [createApplyYoResolveTransform(this.env.conflicter)]),
      createForceYoRcTransform(),
      createForceWriteConfigFiles(),
      ...(withGeneratedFlag ? [generatedAnnotationTransform(this)] : []),
      ...(skipPrettier ? [] : [createApplyPrettierTransform()]),
      createConflicterCheckTransform(this.env.conflicter, conflicterStatus),
      createConflicterStatusTransform(),
    ];
```

In case you dont want to skip the entire formatting you can create a .prettierignore config with this file skipped in there and you will get the same result.